# Can't boot Big Sur 11.2.3 installer. Can't set Startup Disk to createinstallmedia -created installer on M1 MB Air, with Big Sur or Ventura

Tags: startup, install, error

I can't boot a *createinstallmedia -created* installer on M1 on microSD or SSD, with Big Sur 11.2.3, but I can boot one made with Ventura.

I want to reinstall Big Sur 11.2.3, which is what the Mac came with.

While troubleshooting, i noticed I can't set my Startup Disk to a *createinstallmedia -created* installer on M1 on microSD or SSD, with Big Sur or Ventura.   In other words, I can't set my Startup Disk to any of the installers I created with createinstallmedia.  I created them thusly:

```
% sudo /Volumes/Install\ macOS\ Big\ Sur/Install\ macOS\ Big\ Sur.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/SAMSUNG64
Ready to start.
To continue we need to erase the volume at /Volumes/SAMSUNG64.
If you wish to continue type (Y) then press return: y
Erasing disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%... 100%
Copying to disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%... 40%... 50%... 60%... 70%... 80%... 90%... 100%
Making disk bootable...
Install media now available at "/Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur 1"
```

and

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Ventura.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled\ 2

Password:
Ready to start.
To continue we need to erase the volume at /Volumes/Untitled 2.
If you wish to continue type (Y) then press return: Y
Erasing disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%... 100%
Copying essential files...
Copying the macOS RecoveryOS...
Making disk bootable...
Copying to disk: 0%... 10%... 20%... 30%... 40%... 50%... 100%
Install media now available at "/Volumes/Install macOS Ventura"
```

Any troubleshooting/ideas?  I tried some things that gave interesting errors (last few lines):

```
sudo bless --verbose --personalize --folder /Volumes/Install\ macOS\ Big\ Sur/System/Library/CoreServices
Password:
Mount point for /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur/System/Library/CoreServices is /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur
Common mount point of '/Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur/System/Library/CoreServices' and '' is /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur
iBoot found at IODeviceTree:/chosen/iBoot
Mount point for /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur is /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur
Mount point is '/Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur'
No BootX creation requested
This is not an APFS Data-Volume-Parameter-Driven Pre-SSV to SSV case
Saved folder X
Got directory ID of 1196 for /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur/System/Library/CoreServices
Preserving EFI blessed file ID 1279 for /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
finderinfo[0] = 1196
finderinfo[1] = 1279
finderinfo[2] = 0
finderinfo[3] = 0
finderinfo[5] = 1196
Personalization required for volume at /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur
Personalization failed: Error Domain=OSPErrorDomain Code=103 "The given secure boot bundle is invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The given secure boot bundle is invalid.}
Couldn't personalize volume /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur
```

and

```
%  sudo bless --verbose --setBoot --nextonly --mount /Volumes/Install\ macOS\ Big\ Sur 
Mount point for /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur is /Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur
Mount point is '/Volumes/Install macOS Big Sur'
Password for elvey: 
Bootability failed Error Domain=BYErrorDomain Code=100 "Volume not found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Volume not found}
```

Update:  While the above is true, if I boot while I hold down the option key, I am given the option to boot the Ventura installer.  Only.  I want to run the Big Sur installer.  I created the Ventura one solely for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Can you [edit] with some clarifications?  The way your question reads is that your trying to set your boot volume to the “creatinstallmedia” installer location, which makes no sense.  I’m also trying to figure out what the successful media creation screen shots have to do with the question; it’s not clear.  Please try to boil this down to a single succinct statement then build from there.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just boot from the created USB media?  On an M1, you hold the power button down and choose it from the picker.  Random command invocations are not helpful.

Comment: *createinstallmedia -created* is an adjective modifying installer.  In other words, I can't set my Startup Disk to an installer I created with createinstallmedia.

Comment: The question still isn’t clear why are you trying to set an *installer* as a startup disk?  Press and hold the power button to load the boot manager and select the installer - why does this not work for you?  Out of curiosity, did your MBA come with Big Sur or Monetrey preinstalled?

Comment: "load the boot manager and select the installer - why does this not work for you?" As I said, "[At boot,] I am given the option to boot the Ventura installer. Only. " WHY does the system to that? I DO NOT KNOW. What kind of a question is that? If I knew why, I wouldn't be seeking help, now would I?
As I said, I want to run the Big Sur installer.  Is it not obvious that if I could set the  installer to be the startup disk, then (normally) the installer will run upon startup, which would accomplish that goal? 
There are tags on the question: {boot, install, error, startup}... 
Came w/Big Sur.

Comment: Normally it is considered useful when asking for help to tell people what you've already tried, it is not?  Hence my doing so.  Why are you urging me to leave that out?  Seems counter-productive to me.  Why, exactly? And yes, I have the receipt showing the purchase date was prior to Monterey's release.

Comment: I think this question has been dragged through the weeds mainly because of the attempts to bless the installer. If the basic issue is that it will boot from one but not another, then maybe try [MDS](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/mac-deploy-stick/) (freeware, support is a paid option) to download & make the USB installers instead. That way we can eliminate human error without any need to accurately parse what might be going on in terminal or elsewhere.

Comment: Your edit was flagged up to me as I'm following the question - but you don't indicate whether you have yet tried MDS to create your boot sticks.

Comment: MDS does exactly what I did; before doing so, it displays, 'When the Create button is pressed, the admin helper tool will create a macOS Bootable volume by running command shown below. Alternatively, you can run the command manually in Terminal: '"/Volumes/OldOS/Install macOS Big Sur.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia" --volume "/Volumes/26GB" --nointeraction' (except it adds the --nointeraction flag.
So, not surprisingly, I get the same result.

Comment: The thing is - we know MDS never gets it wrong, so that would be a clear indicator of something else at issue. So far you've resisted all attempts to clarify the procedure, for no discernible reason. That just leaves us at am impasse.

Comment: 'I' have resisted?  What are you talking about?  I've done what you've suggested - use MDS.  I've gone with booting from the option-key loaded picker too.  Based on the errors I get with ipsw versions in VirtualOS, it seems to me that Apple is preventing me from reinstalling the last version of the OS that doesn't restrict iOS apps.  Is anyone having success installing 11.2.3 on an add'l volume on an M1?  Not that I've heard of.  I spent the day the Apple Store and multiple Geniuses couldn't figure out how to get it to run.

Comment: It's taken two months for you to tell us you didn't even want the latest version. I'm done now. I have no further useful suggestions to make.

Comment: I've made that clear for ages.  But my earlier question is suppressed: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452153/how-can-i-install-macos-version-11-2-3-build-20d91-or-older-on-my-m1-mac Sorry you weren't aware, but that suppression is not my doing.  Again, I can find no indications *anyone* is having success installing 11.2.3 on an additional volume on an M1.

Comment: I don't think it's within anyone's purview to read back through your question history. Do you? I'm done anyway. This has just become a duplicate of your earlier question, which already has an authoritative answer.

Comment: The last activity there is the comment "You can relax the boot security and bring any OS you please to the hardware - all this is documented in the Apple Platform Security guide and this KB, @WHO'sNoToOldRx4CovidIsMurder – by 
bmike.  (links in original) I was not able to get it to work.  While trying I asked this question.

Comment: I‘m closing this as a duplicate to your original question which still is active and visible on the site, and which has an answer indicating that the installation you are attempting can‘t be done.

Comment: If you used Apple‘s documentation to make it work, please say so in your question, describe the steps you followed and where the process stopped. Right now the question is difficult to follow.

Comment: 1.I don't understand how the close is consistent with my last comment here.  2.You are asking me a question I answered therein when I wrote, "... I was not able to get it to work"